# SQL using if statement in stored procedure to update a table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement, sql-update

I have a table Students with two fields, StudentName and Grade.
I am trying to write a stored procedure to update the Grade.  If the student has an A, I want to change it to B.  If they have a B, I want to change it to A.  If they have anything else I want to leave it alone.  Here is my best attempt

```
create procedure sp_changegrades
if Grade = 'A' update Students set Grade = 'B'

else if Grade = 'B' update Students set Grade = 'A'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just use `CASE`

```
UPDATE Students
SET Grade = 
(
   CASE WHEN Grade = 'A' THEN 'B'
        WHEN Grade = 'B' THEN 'A'
        ELSE Grade     -- "If they have anything else I want to leave it alone."
    END
)
```

or

```
UPDATE Students
SET Grade = 
(
   CASE WHEN Grade = 'A' 
        THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'A'
    END
)
WHERE Grade IN ('A','B')
```

Comment: You could probably add efficiency here by adding a where clause, where Grade in ('A','B')

Answer (score 0):

you can write smth like this. In this solution you define rules of updating in `join` part and then updating.

```
create procedure sp_changegrades
as
begin
    update Students set
        Grade = G.Grade_New
    from Students as S
        inner join (values
            ('A', 'B'),
            ('B', 'A')
        ) as G(Grade_Old, Grade_New) on G.Grade_Old = S.Grade 
end
```

or you can use `case`

```
create procedure sp_changegrades
as
begin
    update Students set
        Grade = 
           case Grade
               when 'A' then 'B'
               when 'B' then 'A'
               else Grade
           end
end
```

Comment: The first query should read `update s set ... from Students as s inner join ...` or `update Students set ... from Students inner join ...`  The second query looks like a copy of John Woo's answer.

Comment: @Andomar you're incorrect about `update s`, the query is correct. The second one looks almost identical to John, because it's obvious solution :) I like `join` solution more because it gives me more freedom, I can update two field following same rules, for example.

Comment: The first query "works" because there is only one reference to Students in the `from` clause.  In that case SQL Server allows you to use both the table name and the alias.  Using this special trick makes your code hard to read.

Comment: @Andomar yes I know that but it still works. I prefer not to use more than one reference to root table in update query. I writing code like this for years. It's not making my code harder to read, in my opinion, it's easier to read - you just cannot use root table more than once, you'll catch compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a Case statement, and add a where clause so you only update the relavant rows.

```
UPDATE Students
SET Grade = 
(
   CASE WHEN Grade = 'A' THEN 'B'
        WHEN Grade = 'B' THEN 'A'
        ELSE Grade     -- "Included for Completeness, should never be utilized."
    END
)
WHERE Grade in ('A','B')
```